# HTML5 export buttons are not working except copy button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I m using HTML5 export buttons in my jquery datatable to export table data. Buttons are displaying properly but not exporting data for pdf/excel except copy button is working fine.
My code is :

```
 table = $(".jqueryDataTable").DataTable( {                 
                        "searching": false,
                    "retrieve": true, 
                    "destroy": true,
                    "ajax": "./getReportDetails",
                    "jQueryUI": true,
                    "dom": 'Bfr<"H"lf><"datatable-scroll"t><"F"ip>',

                     buttons: [
                              'copyHtml5',      
                              'excelHtml5',
                              'csvHtml5',
                              'pdfHtml5' 
                          ], 
                    "fnServerParams": function ( data ) {
                        newData=data;
                        newData.push( { "name": "reportType", "value": reportType }, { "name": "reportSubType", "value": reportSubType}, { "name": "fromDate", "value": fromDate}, { "name": "toDate", "value": toDate});
                    },
                    "columns": [
                                    { "mData": "username", "sTitle": "username"},
                                    { "mData": "transferType", "sTitle": "transferType"}
                        ]
                } );
```

I took reference from [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html). I have included all the required files.
My datatable is showing proper data as well.
Edit : On the click on excel button I am getting javascript exception `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null` in the file `buttons.html5.min.js` and on the click of pdf button I am getting exception 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null` in `pdfmake.min.js`.

What is wrong in my code ?

Comment: Can you create an example on jsFiddle to demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE: These issues have been confirmed by the DataTables author for the Button extension v1.0.3. Fixes have been implemented and should be released with v1.0.4.**

I've had both of these error myself. It seems that the export extension really wants every value as a string.

The problem with the Excel/CSV buttons occurs if you have for example numbers in your dataset.

I have [created a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/osebsuf3/2/) for that issue and reported it to the DataTables project in [this forum topic](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/81728/).

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'tB',
    buttons: ['csv', 'pdf'],
    columns: [
        {
            title: 'Name',
            data: 'name'
        },
        {
            title: 'Age',
            type: 'num',
            data: 'age'
        }
    ],
    data: [
        {name: 'John Doe', age: 25},
        {name: null, age: 37}
    ]
});
```

I've also had the second problem with the PDF button. In my case, this was caused by a null value, but that I haven't managed to reproduce in a fiddle yet. (The above fiddle *does* contain a null value yet it *does not* cause the crash. I don't know what's different in my real-world case.)

@Puneet, maybe you're able to edit the fiddle to be more similar to your issue to reproduce that problem you're having and then report it to DataTables.

I'm still hoping that this might get fixed in the DataTables core runtime, but until then, one workaround you can apply is that you set the `orthogonal` data type in your button's `exportOptions` to e.g. `export`, and then you define a separate `export` function as the `render`er of that column, which converts it to a string.